# Making variable for each iteration in foreach loop SwiftUI

Tags: swift, loops, swiftui, foreach

I have a nestled foreach loop and I want to modify data for each element in the nestled loop. Like this:

```
struct trainingView: View {

   @ObservedObject var workout: Workout

   @State private var reps: Int = 0

    
   var body: some View {
       ForEach(workout.exercises, id: \.self) { exercise in

            Text(exercise.nameOfExercise)


            ForEach(0..<exercise.amountOfSets, id: \.self) { Set in

                 Text("\(Set+1) Set")
                 Text(reps)
                 Stepper("Reps", value: $reps , in: 0...30)

                 }
              }
           }
         }
```

I would like the variable rep to be independent from changes in an another elements stepper. If you need better examples of the code just ask.

This does not work as one change affects all elements. I have also tried making an @State object in the nestled loop but this doesn't work either. I have also tried making an array to store the data but this seemed complicated since the size of the array can change from different times. I have tried to search for the information on here but haven't found anyone answering it. I am fairly new to swiftUI and in need of help.

Comment: Should there be an individual reps value for each Exercise & Set?

Comment: Yes that is precisely right

Comment: Without them being able to affect another one when changed.

Comment: OK, that's precisely what my answer does, but I'll adapt it to use your object names

Comment: `ForEach` is a `View` not a for loop and `id: \.self` is a mistake

Answer (score 0):

The `Stepper` in your example takes a Binding to a numeric value. If you create an array-of-arrays, you can create a Binding by accessing each row and element within it via their indices, e.g.:

```
struct Exercise: Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    var sets: [Set]
}

struct Set: Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let requiredReps: Int = 10
    var reps: Int = 0
}

class Workout: ObservableObject {

    @Published var exercises: [Exercise]

    init(exercises: [Exercise]) {
        self.exercises = exercises
    }    
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject var workout = Workout(exercises: [
        Exercise(name: "Squats", sets: [Set(name: "Set 1"), Set(name: "Set 2"), Set(name: "Set 3")]),
        Exercise(name: "Lunges", sets: [Set(name: "Set 1"), Set(name: "Set 2"), Set(name: "Set 3")]),
        Exercise(name: "Burpees", sets: [Set(name: "Set 1"), Set(name: "Set 2"), Set(name: "Set 3")])
    ])
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(workout.exercises) { exercise in
                Section(exercise.name) {
                    let rowIndex = workout.exercises.firstIndex(of: exercise)!
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(exercise.sets) { set in
                            let objectIndex = exercise.sets.firstIndex(of: set)!
                            VStack {
                                Text(set.name + ": ") + Text(set.reps, format: .number) + Text("/") + Text(set.requiredReps, format: .number)
                                
                                Stepper("Reps", value: $workout.exercises[rowIndex].sets[objectIndex].reps, in: 0...set.requiredReps)
                                    .labelsHidden()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I a having a hard time implementing this into my code. I am passing a class Workout to this view which consists of two parts a workout name and an array of a struct called Exercise. The first foreach loop is an array of the exercises and the nestled one is an array of exercise.sets. So the point is I want a variable "reps" to be independent for each set in each exercise so I can change its value.

Comment: Please update your question to show the actual problem you're having

Comment: I have now updated the question

Comment: I've updated the answer to use the same class / struct names you used. Hopefully this will allow you to understand it more easily.